# Trouble reading npy file

Tags: python

I am new to python and am having trouble reading a *.npy file that somebody else saved.  If I use the following commands:

```
import numpy as np
np.load('lat.npy')
```

I get the following error:
`ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False`

So, I set allow_pickle=True:
`np.load('lat.npy',allow_pickle=True)`

Then, I get a different error:
`OSError: Failed to interpret file 'lat.npy' as a pickle`

Maybe it is relevant that I am on a PC, and the other file was written on a Mac.

Am I doing something wrong?  (I am sorry if this question has been asked already.)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I learned that my colleague's data file was written in python 2, while I am using python 3.  Using the np.load command with the following options will work:

```
np.load('lat.npy',allow_pickle=True,fix_imports=True,encoding='latin1')
```

It seems I need to set all of those options, but the 'encoding' argument seems especially important.  The doc for numpy.load says about the encoding argument, "Only useful when loading Python 2 generated pickled files in Python 3, which includes npy/npz files containing object arrays."